# cannot parse JSON : org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I am working on an App which needs an API. I have made an API but when i try to parse it into my listview it doesnt work it gives th error message "org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject". Here is my code
Things.java:
http://pastebin.com/29mKyUMV
Json:
http://pastebin.com/B98KZA9K

(I already tried converting JSONObject to JSONArray but it didnt work)

Hope someone can help me

greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a `JSONArray` can't be a `JSONObject`. Change

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr); 
// Getting JSON Array node
contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("");
```

with

```
contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```